# explanation of use_map_topic in amcl?

Tags: navigation, move-base, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In AMCL page, for use_map_topic it says "When set to true, AMCL will subscribe to the map topic rather than making a service call to receive its map." but i dont get it. can someone explain it?

I created map with gmapping and saved it. After when i try to localize the robot in the static map  how should i set this parameter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238388/explanation-of-use_map_topic-in-amcl?/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you created a map in advance, you also need the map_server to publish the map. I think in this case it doesn't really matter whether you use the map-topic or the map-service, as map_server provides both. So you can leave the parameter to false here. But other map providers like mappers might provide only the topic or the service.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1